# Convert SQL query to linq with union

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT
    a.DocumentNumber, a.ItemNumber, 
    SUM(a.ItemAmount) AS ItemAmount 
FROM
    (SELECT
         SopNumbe AS DocumentNumber, ITEMNMBR AS ItemNumber, 
         XTNDPRCE AS ItemAmount
     FROM
         dbo.SOP30300 
     WHERE
         SOPNUMBE = '8403017              ' 
         AND XTNDPRCE <> 0
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
         LAPTODNM AS DocumentNumber, LITMNMBR AS ItemNumber, 
         -1 * ta.APPTOAMT AS ItemAmount 
     FROM
         dbo.RM20201 a 
     LEFT JOIN
         dbo.TRM20201 ta ON a.APFRDCNM = ta.LAPFRDNM 
                         AND a.APTODCNM = ta.LAPTODNM 
     WHERE
         ta.LAPTODNM = '8403017              ') a
GROUO BY
    a.DocumentNumber, a.ItemNumber 
HAVING
    SUM(a.ItemAmount) > 0
```

Here is the linq I am trying

```
var result = (from sop in _librgContext.Sop30300
              where sop.Sopnumbe == "8403017" && sop.Xtndprce != 0
              select new InvoiceSummary
              {
                  DocumentNumber = sop.Sopnumbe,
                  ItemNumber = sop.Itemnmbr,
                  ItemAmount = sop.Xtndprce
              })
  .Union(
  from rm in _librgContext.Rm20201
  join ta in _librgContext.TRM20201 on new { Key1 = rm.ApplyFromDocumentNumber, Key2 = rm.ApplyToDocumentNumber } equals new { Key1 = ta.Lapfrdnm, Key2 = ta.Laptodnm } into joinResult
  from ta in joinResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where ta != null && ta.Laptodnm == "8403017" // Added null check for ta
                                               // && rm.GLPOSTDT <= CutoffDate // Uncomment if @CutoffDate is a parameter
  select new InvoiceSummary
  {
      DocumentNumber = ta.Laptodnm, // Adjusted to use LAPTODNM from ta
      ItemNumber = ta.Litmnmbr,
      ItemAmount = -1 * (ta != null ? rm.ApplyToAmount : 0)
  })
  .GroupBy(a => new { a.DocumentNumber, a.ItemNumber })
  .Where(g => g.Sum(a => a.ItemAmount) > 0)
  .Select(g => new InvoiceSummary
  {
      DocumentNumber = g.Key.DocumentNumber,
      ItemNumber = g.Key.ItemNumber,
      ItemAmount = g.Sum(a => a.ItemAmount)
  });
```

Got the following on debugging `Unable to translate set operation when matching columns on both sides have different store types.`

Comment: Are those ApplyFrom, ApplyTo fields, that aren't in the source sql by the way, strings or number types? Besides when you have working presumably optimized sql already why transform it into Linq that is presumably less optimized when retranslated from Linq into Sql by the framework? In my eyes this isn't an improvement.

Comment: both are type char

Comment: As I have context created I am trying in linq approach

Comment: If i recall correctly there was a problem with char types when their lengths differ. You may try explicit Convert.ToString() calls on the 4 fields used in the join to enforce some kind of cast functionality in the backing database to a varchar equivalent type.

Comment: Side note: `LEFT JOIN` makes no sense when you have a `WHERE` on the same table. Either move the condition to the `ON` or change to an `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @Ralf I have the field as follows in my context I am generating the POCO from database `[Key]
[Column("APFRDCNM")]
[StringLength(21)]
[Unicode(false)]
public string ApplyFromDocumentNumber { get; set; } = null!;`

Comment: As I know it is known problem with EF Core, in version 8 they claim it is fixed.

Comment: Anyway, for `UNION ALL`, you should use `Concat`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I tried but no luck

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: I used Union instead of Concat

Comment: So, you have missed important comment that EF Core 8 required. Concat/Union - has no difference if translator won't process query.

Comment: With out UNION it works good even in UNION I tried returning empty values still no luck

Comment: Googling gave me second result [Set operations over non-entity projections with different facets](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19129) - fixed in EF Core 8. Yes it is the same symptoms with nulls. And as I know there are no workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I am able to do this which is working as expected as of now

```
var result1 = (
from sop in _librgContext.Sop30300
where sop.Sopnumbe == sopNumber && sop.Xtndprce != 0
select new InvoiceSummary
{
  DocumentNumber = sop.Sopnumbe,
  ItemNumber = sop.Itemnmbr,
  ItemAmount = sop.Xtndprce
}).ToList(); // Execute the query to bring the data into memory

    var result2 = (
        from rm in _librgContext.Rm20201
        join ta in _librgContext.TRM20201
        on new
        {
            rm.ApplyFromDocumentNumber,
             rm.ApplyToDocumentNumber
        } equals new
        {
            ApplyFromDocumentNumber = ta.Lapfrdnm,
            ApplyToDocumentNumber = ta.Laptodnm
        } into joinResult
        from ta in joinResult.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where ta != null && ta.Laptodnm == sopNumber
        select new InvoiceSummary
        {
            DocumentNumber = ta.Laptodnm, // Removed ToString() conversion
            ItemNumber = ta.Litmnmbr, // Removed ToString() conversion
            ItemAmount = -1 * (ta != null ? rm.ApplyToAmount : 0)
        }).ToList(); // Execute the query to bring the data into memory

    var combinedResult = result1.Concat(result2)
        .GroupBy(a => new { a.DocumentNumber, a.ItemNumber })
        .Where(g => g.Sum(a => a.ItemAmount) > 0)
        .Select(g => new InvoiceSummary
        {
            DocumentNumber = g.Key.DocumentNumber,
            ItemNumber = g.Key.ItemNumber,
            ItemAmount = g.Sum(a => a.ItemAmount)
        });

    var finalResult = combinedResult.ToList();
```